# c++ - size of std::bitset<0>?

Tags: c++, bitset

I thought the size of `std::bitset<0> myBS` would be `0`, while `std::cout << sizeof(myBS)` print out `1`. Can anyone please explain me that? Does that mean a bitset can never be null?

Comment: It means that a C++ object can never be less than 1 byte. The standard guarantees it.

Comment: `sizeof` can never yield 0 in Standard C++

Comment: "can be null" is a dangerous term in C++. In languages like SQL and Java, objects can be NULL. In C++, this isn't the case. _Pointers_ can be null, and that's about it. Integers can be zero, and strings can be empty, but neither is "null".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` can never return zero in C++. An object's size is at least one (except in the case of empty base classes). If this were not the case, then you could have an array of objects where all the objects would be stored at the same address.

The value of `sizeof(std::bitset<N>)` is actually irrelevant, anyway. The `std::bitset<N>` class provides an *interface* to a sequence of `N` bits. If `N` = 0, the standard guarantees that this interface is to exactly 0 bits. This is true no matter how large the object is. No matter how many bits are in that object, you can only use 0 of them.

Comment: thank you, `interface` is the word i was looking for. I misinterpreted the number of bit elements in the bitset as the size, while it's the cardinality.